# Installing HunterGate dependencies locally

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Maybe I'm missing something but to me, HunterGate is like a package manager where it downloads and manages the dependencies that are specified in the CMakeLists (assuming that they are supported by HunterGate). Great! However, it doesn't quite work in my situation the way I need it. I have a project, let's call it `Foo`, I have two targets, `FooTest` and `Foo` in my CMakeLists, `Foo` is a shared library that is linked with Boost::regex and `FooTest` is an executable that is linked with `GTest`. Note that I compiled all those dependencies dynamically (using `-fPIC`) which is possible by adding this in my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(HUNTER_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
```

Because my library is shared so it needs to link against the shared objects of Boost. So this works great for compiling the library but my tests don't work properly because the boost libraries are not installed my machine, that's good and actually expected but on the other hand, how do I run the tests? I can install boost with a brew command or other means but isn't that defeating the purpose of HunterGate? I could just skip HunterGate and do that in the beginning. Maybe there is a way to install the libraries HunterGate compiles?